# nginx - replacing header

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a integrations.conf file which looks as follows:

```
http {

    map $http_host $csp_header {
        default "'self'";
         "~*.*\.something.com" "https://*.something.ai https://*.something.com";
         "~*.*\.something.ai" "https://*.something.ai https://*.something.com";
    }

    include  common/base.conf;
    include  common/secure_headers.conf;

    server {

        location ~ /api {
            include some_other_file.conf
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

The secure_headers.conf looks as follows:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "sameorigin";
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors $csp_header"; 
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
```

Now, for a particular path "/api/this-path", I want to replace the values for `x-frame-options` and `context-security-policy` headers to:

```
X-Frame-Options "*";
Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors *";
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How does Nginx handle `/api/this-path`? You could place it in its own `location` block. Alternatively, you could use one or more `map` directives to generate the header values (extending what you already have).

Comment: @RichardSmith, there is already a location block in my file which uses "/api". Adding another "/api/this-path" location block seperately or as a nested block inside "/api" didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try additional `map` blocks?

```
map $uri $csp_value {
    ~^/api/this-path  "frame-ancestors *";
    default           "frame-ancestors $csp_header";
}
map $uri $xfo_value
    ~^/api/this-path  "*";
    defalut           "sameorigin";
}
...
server {
    ...
    add_header X-Frame-Options $xfo_value;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy $csp_value; 
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    ...
```